# Slim Image Cropper Not Sending the cropped image to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor-pages

I am using the Slim Image Cropper jQuery library to allow the user upload a profile picture and crop it. The whole thing works fine except that the image being saved is the original image and not the cropped one. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 mb-3">
    <div class="slim"
         data-ratio="1:1"
         data-size="270,270"
         data-edit="false"
         data-instant-edit="true"                                     
         data-max-file-size="2">
        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ProfilePicture))
        {
             <input type="hidden" id="profilePicture" name="ProfilePicture" value="@Model.ProfilePicture" />
             <input type="file" id="profilePictureFile" name="ProfilePictureFile[]" />
             <img src="@Model.ProfilePicture">                                        
        }
        else
        {
             <input type="file" id="profilePictureFile" name="ProfilePictureFile[]" />                                        
        }
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var formdata = new FormData();

    var file = document.getElementById('profilePictureFile');
    var imgfile = file.files;

    if (imgfile && imgfile != null && imgfile.length > 0) {
         formdata.append(imgfile[0].name, imgfile[0]);
         formdata.append('ProfilePictureFile', imgfile[0]);
    }
    
    // I then submit the formdata variable using AJAX post request.
</script>
```

Comment: You're appending the original file content to the FormData object, not the result of the Slim library. Check their documentation for how you invoke the cropping functionality and access the result.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I read through the docs - https://pqina.nl/slim/ it supposed to automatically do that but it isn't.

Comment: Never mind it doesn't say automatically. but I do not see an invoke functionality in their docs.

Comment: Have you paid for a licenced copy?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes. I messaged the author but my support has expired not sure they will respond.

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution. Instead of working with the input `type="file"`, Slim Image Cropper creates a hidden input with the edited image details where it is storing the value as a base64 string. I am posting the value to the server and then converting it into an image.

```
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ProfilePicture))
                {
                    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProfileImageCropper>(model.ProfilePicture);

                    byte[] imageBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(result.output.image.Replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,","").Replace("data:image/png;base64,", ""));
                    
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
                    {
                        Image profileImage = Image.FromStream(ms, true);

                        if (profileImage != null)
                        {                            
                            string _FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(result.output.name);
                            string _FileName = model.UserUniqueID.ToLower() + _FileExtension;
                            string _path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/assets/images/profile/"), _FileName);

                            string currentFile = UserProfileRepository.GetProfilePictureName(model.ProfileID);
                                                        
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentFile))
                                if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(currentFile)))                         
                                    System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath(currentFile));                                                                
                                                        
                            profileImage.Save(_path);
                            model.ProfilePicture = "/assets/images/profile/" + _FileName;                            
                        }
                    }
                }
```